# Chrome extension to disable spellcheck in a text field?

Tags: osx, chrome, spell-checker

I occasionally need to write Latin in a text box in Chrome. And this always happens:

> [image]

I don't really want to break out a dedicated text editor just for this, but the red lines under most words really bug me. I'd like a Chrome (37.0.2062.124 on OS X 10.9.5) extension that:

- Turns off spell check on command (Ideally I'd like it to be through a right click menu, but any decent way is fine).
- It's fine if it turns off spellcheck for the whole page, but only one text field would be better.
- *Doesn't* just disable it for the whole browser, only one text field or page.
- Failing being able to turn *off* spellcheck, at least removes the red lines.

Bonus: Switching to Latin spellcheck instead of turning it off would also be fine.

Is there an extension that does this?

Comment: Why disable and not switch to Latin? And I suppose you mean disable just for that text field or page, and not for the rest of Chrome (which you can do from the right-click menu)?

Comment: @Gilles It'd be okay to switch to Latin, but what I really don't want is to jump through a bunch of hoops every time I write Latin in Chrome. And yes, just one text field or page (clarifying both in the question).

Comment: @Undo I can create a userscript for you, but one question: is this for `textarea`'s or normal `input` fields? Or both...?

Comment: @ṧнʊß it'll only be for one, but I can find out right now. I'll let you know in a little while. Thanks!

Comment: @ṧнʊß It's a `textarea` inside a `div#message-box`, which is eventually inside a form. It's a phpBB forum thing, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a Userscript to add a button after all `textarea` elements to disable `spellcheck`. Most browsers (I think, through a bit of Googling) recognise this and stop spellchecking if they see `spellcheck='false'`, but I've only tested on Google Chrome.

Get it [here](https://gist.github.com/shu8/a1e652178ff4483c5c9d).

To install, either:

- install Tampermonkey and add the script, or
- go to `chrome://extensions` and drag the script after downloading and unzipping the zip

Please do tell me if anything doesn't work right - it's been tested on a simple form, and that's it.

[image]

Known problems:

- After clicking button, you need to cut and paste back into the same textarea or the spell check will not have 'updated' - sorry! Don't know if it's possible to be fixed.

Comment: Note this script is just an edited version of my [previous answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14125/2675)

Answer (score 1):

No extension needed, just right click in the box, Spell Checker Options, untick Check Spelling of text fields.  *Better yet if you have a latin language pack installed on your system you can select latin spell checking.*

[image: Screen Shot]

**Correction:** - While Chrome has a Latin language setting on my system it says "this language cannot be used for spell checking.

Comment: This is close, but it seems to be 'sticky' throughout the browser (I.e. I just did that on my Latin page, but it killed spellcheck on an SE answer I was writing in another tab). I'd really like it to only apply to one text field or page.

Comment: Shame - but then again Chrome isn't a word processor!