# Chrome extension to 'eliminate' choices on multiple-choice questions

Tags: chrome

I take multiple-choice quizes in my browser. The questions look like this:

[image]

One of the techniques I use when answering a multiple-choice question is to eliminate obviously incorrect answers. In this case, I'd like to eliminate the fourth choice.

My teacher uses HTML that looks like this:

```
<font size="+1" color="#000000"><input type="RADIO" name="answer" value="4">
 Popsicles
</font>
```

I'd like a Chrome extension that:

- Detects these radio options, and
- Adds an option to the right-click menu (or equivalent accessible thing) called "Eliminate" or something similar
- When clicked, the extension should indicate in some way that the answer obviously isn't right - maybe grey it out, disable the option, etc.

Is there an extension that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Userscript**

I've made a userscript as an answer to this. It disables the radio button so you can't click it (and kind of grays it out). You can get it over [***here***](https://gist.github.com/shu8/2a25e8b8d17caa60c78a).

Read the comment at the bottom of that link for details on what to change to make it work.

To use it, **download the zip, unzip it, and drag the `disabler.user.js` file to `chrome://extensions`**.

Alternatively, install [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) and add the file there.

Please do tell me if anything doesn't work - I've only tested it with a simple form.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner on this, it works perfect.